# Microsoft Graph SDK is accepting the PATCH request for file Metadata update but nothing gets updated?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, azure-functions

Only scenario it is failing is,  when we don't pass the required field in initial fileUploadWithMetadata call, post that we are not able to update any field of SharePoint case(folder) or caseItem(document inside folder)

Anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: private async Task < bool > UpdateMetadataForItemPath(string driveId, string itemPath, IDictionary < string, object > dataDictionary) {

    var result =
      await GetDriveItemWithPath(itemPath, driveId, null).ListItem.Fields.Request()
      .WithMaxRetry(0)
      .UpdateAsync(new FieldValueSet {
        AdditionalData = dataDictionary
      });

    return result != null;

Comment: this is my method @CarlZhao